# How to parse contents from a list of dicts in json using python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

My json file :

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "features": {
            "location": "West Springfield, MA",
            "geo_type": "User location",
            "screen_name": "JtTatro",
            "primary_geo": "West Springfield, MA",
            "id": 2158092352,
            "tweets": 1,
            "name": "Jim Tatro"
        },
        "user_id": 2158092352
    }

,
{
            "features": {
                "location": "Tijuana, Baja California",
                "geo_type": "User location",
                "screen_name": "YuitziContreras",
                "primary_geo": "Tijuana, Baja California",
                "id": 996917180980744193,
                "tweets": 1,
                "name": "yuitzi contreras"
            },
            "user_id": 996917180980744193
        }
    ]
}
```

i am trying to parse the data stored in the features dict. My code so far:

```
import json

input_file = open ('file.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
tweet_list = []
features_list = []
user_list =[]

for item in json_array:
        for item2 in json_array[item]:
            tweet_list.append(item2)


for features,user in tweet_list:
    print(features,user)
```

the code above returns the dict names : `features, user_id`. how would it be possible to get the contents of each dict field so that i can pass them to my database?

For example, get location, geo_type etc.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's your desired output? And you clearly know how to access elements in a dict, so what's preventing you from getting that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse the `features` using a list comprehension:

```
features = [v['features'] for v in json_array['data']]
```

If any row doesn't have a key called `features` then `v['features']` would throw a `KeyError`.

To avoid that

```
features = [v['features'] for v in json_array['data'] if 'features' in v.keys()]
```

similarly `user_list` can be constructed.

And finally, `tweet_list`, *which seems functionally to be the `zip` of `features` & `user_list`*,  can be directly constructed using the list comprehension & dictionary unpacking, like this:

```
tweet_list = [dict(v['features'], **{'user_id': v['user_id']}) 
              for v in json_array['data']
              if 'features' in v.keys() and 'user_id' in v.keys()]

# tweet_list outputs:

[{'geo_type': 'User location',
  'id': 2158092352,
  'location': 'West Springfield, MA',
  'name': 'Jim Tatro',
  'primary_geo': 'West Springfield, MA',
  'screen_name': 'JtTatro',
  'tweets': 1,
  'user_id': 2158092352},
 {'geo_type': 'User location',
  'id': 996917180980744193,
  'location': 'Tijuana, Baja California',
  'name': 'yuitzi contreras',
  'primary_geo': 'Tijuana, Baja California',
  'screen_name': 'YuitziContreras',
  'tweets': 1,
  'user_id': 996917180980744193}]

# features outputs
[{'geo_type': 'User location',
  'id': 2158092352,
  'location': 'West Springfield, MA',
  'name': 'Jim Tatro',
  'primary_geo': 'West Springfield, MA',
  'screen_name': 'JtTatro',
  'tweets': 1},
 {'geo_type': 'User location',
  'id': 996917180980744193,
  'location': 'Tijuana, Baja California',
  'name': 'yuitzi contreras',
  'primary_geo': 'Tijuana, Baja California',
  'screen_name': 'YuitziContreras',
  'tweets': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, `[]` represents an array, while `{}` represents an object. Python parses a JSON object (e.g. `{"features": ..., "user_id": ...}`) as a dict. You should use `.items()` method to get key-value pairs from a dict. Iterating over a dict only gives the keys.